# Any recommendations on an End-of-Life components tracking tool?

Tags: web-apps, web-services, version-control

When using a multitude of different software deployment paths and having to manage many different environments, it's sometimes hard to keep track of versions of the single components.
For example, if you are supporting different hosting scenarios for several customers:

- Some deploy software on single servers using the package manager
- Other tools might be installed using Docker
- A third application is installed in some K8s Cluster using some helm chart
- ...

This list goes on forever.
You need to keep track of the OS- or K8s-version and every single application for:

- is the resource nearing its end-of-life?
- is there any newer version of it, bringing new features?
- is there any newer version because of a security or otherwise urgent fix, which needs to be treated different than skipable feature-updates?

For CI/CD managed software components, there are tools like [renovate](https://github.com/renovatebot/renovate) or the GitLab bot to track your 3rd party dependencies for your code.
But when you need to track non-code versions for a whole OS or even versions of software you are enrolling to Workstations, renovate and friends will reach their limits fast.

I'm looking for a software recommendation (if software like that even exists), which receives a list of version updates from multiple, configurable sources like:

- https://endoflife.date/
- RSS Feeds of software projects
- Mailing list announcements
- A self-maintained list
- ...

If, for example, there is an Instance of [GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/categories/releases/) deployed in some K8s Cluster in Version 16.7.2 and there are the following updates released:

1. [16.7.3](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2024/01/12/gitlab-16-7-3-released/), which fixes an uncritical issue with the database
2. [16.7.4](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2024/01/25/critical-security-release-gitlab-16-8-1-released/), which fixes a critical security issue
3. [16.8.0](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2024/01/18/gitlab-16-8-released/), which brings some additional features and is a minor update release

then I'd like to have the tool provide different kind of support to track that there are (partially) important actions to take. For example:

- Provide a Dashboard which shows green for up2date, yellow for "newer version available" and "red for X days till end-of-life or important security update available"
- Create tickets to execute the update in Tools like Jira, Monday, ClickUp, etc.
- Send mails to the customer/project responsible
- etc.

An RSS feed is just informing about any update to be available for some software.
But it does not inform about:

- projects or customers using this software
- if that is a nice-to-have update or an urgent one
- where that software is installed (server names, stages, ...)

Ideally, this tool should be available as some kind of Web-App.

Is anyone aware of such a tool or project?